# Mongoose model not persisting object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, redux, axios

In a nutshell, I'm working on a math assessment app that takes your answers and stores them in a database and I'm having trouble adding more than one object to the backend. The Mongoose model is as such:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Algebra1Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  answers: {
    type: Object
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

module.exports = algebra1 = mongoose.model('algebra1', Algebra1Schema)
```

Here is the route:

```
// Submit application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

router.post('/', [jsonParser, auth], async (req, res) => {

  try {
    let newTest = new algebra1({
      answers: req.body,
      user: req.user.id
    })
    await newTest.save();
    res.json(req.body);

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the update action that makes an axios POST request:

```
export const submit = (results, history) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    const res = await axios.post('/api/algebra1', results, config);

    // dispatch({
    //   type: QuestionActionTypes.RESET
    // })

    dispatch(setAlert('You\;ve finished your assessment!', 'success'));
    history.push('/results');

  } catch (err) {

    console.error(err.message);
    // dispatch({
    //   type: PROFILE_ERROR,
    //   payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    // })
  }
}
```

I want to add a percentage item to the algebra1 model, that looks like this:

```
const Algebra1Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  answers: {
    type: Object
  },
**percent:{
    type: Number**
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})
```

When I changed the route to have a percent Number added, the request goes to the database, but the answers object and percent Number aren't included. I tried updating the route to:

```
 let newTest = new algebra1({
      answers: req.body.answers,
      percent: req.body.percent
      user: req.user.id
    })
```

I tried adding the following before the axios POST request:

```
 const body = JSON.stringify({ results, percent });
```

and using body in place of results in the axios POST request, but the same result; nothing was persisted to the database except the user.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I thought maybe the **results** object I'm sending in my action isn't correct, but when I only send the answers as req.body, it goes through and the database has the answers object.

Comment: Mongoose only saves data that strictly adheres to the schema. "Object" is an mixed type. as in god knows what type of data is in there. Mongoose does not watch such data and you have to do something like `algebra1.markModified("answers");` before you `algebra1.save();` or it will not persist.

Comment: With that said. `percent: { type: Number }` is not a mixed type, and should persist. At least if it is actually a number as the schema says. like `12` or `24.5`. The reason I point this out is because you mention that the "percent object" isn't included. If it IS an object and not an number, then it will not persist. Terminology is key so we know that we are speaking about the same thing.

Comment: I read that it was a mixed type, and "answers" is a one-dimensional JSON object, so maybe that's why I didn't have to use markModified? Also, you are correct, I mean to say the percent Number, and have updated the question to reflect that.